# iOS crash on App Store review inside autolayout methods

Tags: ios, crash

I have a problem with an app rejected during App Store review with the reason that it crashes on launch. It works without issues or autolayout warnings for me in debug and release configurations (when installed from TestFlight). Stack trace does not include any app code except the main function.

Please help to identify the possible issue.

Relevant part of crash log:

```
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000073006910
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018061db90 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x00000001818dbc38 -[NSISLinearExpression enumerateVariablesAndCoefficients:] + 284
2   Foundation                      0x00000001818df078 -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:] + 352
3   Foundation                      0x00000001818dcc88 -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 600
4   Foundation                      0x00000001818dc00c -[NSISEngine tryAddingDirectly:] + 140
5   Foundation                      0x00000001818db8a0 -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 540
6   Foundation                      0x00000001818db53c -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 284
7   Foundation                      0x00000001818d9138 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 228
8   UIKit                           0x0000000186201a70 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 468
9   UIKit                           0x0000000186201840 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 72
10  UIKit                           0x00000001862016e8 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 288
11  UIKit                           0x00000001862015ac -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _addConstraint:] + 280
12  UIKit                           0x00000001862061a8 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 1048
13  UIKit                           0x000000018620209c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 244
14  UIKit                           0x0000000186205d80 -[UILabel updateConstraints] + 220
15  UIKit                           0x0000000186992ee4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 460
16  UIKit                           0x000000018699314c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 200
17  UIKit                           0x0000000186992e14 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 252
18  Foundation                      0x00000001818d8cc0 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
19  UIKit                           0x0000000186204d98 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64
20  UIKit                           0x0000000186993120 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 156
21  UIKit                           0x0000000186992e14 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 252
22  Foundation                      0x00000001818d8cc0 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
23  UIKit                           0x0000000186204d98 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64
24  UIKit                           0x0000000186993120 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 156
25  UIKit                           0x0000000186992e14 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 252
26  UIKit                           0x000000018699314c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 200
27  UIKit                           0x0000000186205c7c __60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 100
28  Foundation                      0x00000001818d8cc0 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
29  UIKit                           0x0000000186204d98 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64
30  UIKit                           0x00000001862058b0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 244
31  UIKit                           0x0000000186223110 -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 108
32  UIKit                           0x00000001869937f0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 268
33  UIKit                           0x0000000186410aa0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 176
34  UIKit                           0x00000001860f8210 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 700
35  QuartzCore                      0x0000000183a8a994 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
36  QuartzCore                      0x0000000183a855d0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
37  QuartzCore                      0x0000000183a85490 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
38  QuartzCore                      0x0000000183a84ac0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
39  QuartzCore                      0x0000000183a84820 CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
40  QuartzCore                      0x0000000183a7dde4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
41  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180f5c728 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
42  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180f5a4cc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
43  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180e84c70 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 416
44  UIKit                           0x000000018616b94c -[UIApplication _run] + 460
45  UIKit                           0x0000000186166088 UIApplicationMain + 204
46  MyApp                       0x0000000100095a38 main (AppDelegate.swift:13)
47  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180a228b8 start + 4
```

Comment: What device did they test on?  What device do you test on?

Comment: Their log strangely omits device name, it has: 
Hardware Model:      xxx
And I have tested on different devices and simulators, the issue wasn't reproduced on any.

Comment: Have you tested an ad-hoc build?

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me as well.

Comment: Is there anything unusual in your first view controller's layout? If you cannot replicate the issue you might need to use one of your TSIs (https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/).

Comment: Your first view controller is crashing. Can you post the code?

Comment: It may be you're adding or removing subviews while app is changing/modifying autolayouts, for instance device is rotated, and while it's rotated some uiview is removed or added. Anyway, we need to see the code of UIViewController, to tell you more.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help, it was not related to autolayout. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was memory issue not related to autolayout and caused by bug in Swift 2.2 compiler which is already fixed in Swift 2.2.1 (Xcode 7.3.1).
Autolayout methods just happened to access invalid memory address caused by other code. It was reproduced on AppStore review and was not reproducible for me because I had Xcode 7.3.1 and build to AppStore was created from different machine with Xcode 7.3.